# How do I remove a character from strings of different lengths with sql? Intersystems cache sql

Tags: sql, string-formatting, intersystems-cache

I have a column of strings that have an '&' at the beginning and end of each one that I need to remove for a Crystal report I'm creating. I'm writing the SQL code outside of Crystal I am using Intersystems Cache SQL. Below is an example:

```
&This&         This
&is&           is
&What&         what
&it&           I
&looks&        need
&like&         it
&now&          to
               look
               like
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **PLEASE** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: Actually, I refreshed my browser and the formatting is how I intended it to look.

Comment: You helped me format it. Thank you! I'll read the material you supplied. I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the ampersands are always positioned as both the leading and trailing characters, here's at least maybe a start. Use a combination of `SUBSTR` (or `SUBSTRING`, if using stream data) and `LENGTH`, like so:

```
SELECT SUBSTR((SELECT column FROM table), 2, LENGTH(SELECT column FROM table) - 2)
```

This should return a substring that starts counting at the 2nd character [of the original string, given by the first sub-expression/argument to `SUBSTR`], counting up for the total number of characters [of the original string] less 2 (i.e. less the two ampersands).

If you need to including trailing blanks and/or the string termination character, you may need to use a different variation of the `LENGTH` function. See resources for details on these functions and their variants:

https://docs.intersystems.com/irislatest/csp/docbook/DocBook.UI.Page.cls?KEY=RSQL_substr

https://cedocs.intersystems.com/latest/csp/docbook/DocBook.UI.Page.cls?KEY=RSQL_length

Comment: Is there any way to achieve the same thing in a WHERE clause? or does it have to be in a SELECT statement? Thank you!

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly what you mean here, the `WHERE` clause would go inside your `SELECT` subexpressions, like so: `SELECT SUBSTR((SELECT column FROM table WHERE ... ), 2, LENGTH(SELECT column FROM table WHERE ...) - 2)`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a Crystal formula that does the same:

```
ExtractString({YourData},"&","&")
```